# How to jump in the next row on press enter

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a simple form and i want that on press enter go to the next dropdown list.

```
<tbody>
      <tr id="line1">
      <td style="width: 20px; text-align: center; padding-right: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">1</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity1" value="" id="quantity01" class="text" style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"></td>
      <td><select name="product1" id="product01" class="chzn-select chzn-done" data-placeholder="Choose a Product" style="width: 270px; display: none;">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">123456 TEXT </option>
<option value="2">5454654 TEXT 2</option>
</select>
      <td><select name="tax_rate1" id="tax_rate01" class="chzn-select chzn-done" data-placeholder="Select..." style="width: 110px; display: none;">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
      <td><input type="text" name="input" value="" id="input" class="text" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;"></td>
      </tr>
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Would'nt it be more intuitive to use tabindex? On the other hand, did you mean the next select or the next option (there's arrow keys for options) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").keypress(function(e){

var key = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

// If keycode is 13, this means it's "enter"
if(key == 13)
    $(this).next().focus();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

ParPar's answer misses the "n" of function (I edited it) but works.

Here's a [working example at JSFiddle](http://tinyurl.com/d83mjbh).